# AWS S3 bucket error in Fetching AWS gateway API

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a simple API that works in my browser through the url:

```
https://XXX.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testing/calculator?x=test&y=testing
```

I get a 200 response there.

The problem is when I try to take 2 inputs from an HTML page then pass them into the API to get the response and display the data on the html page I get an error saying: **An error occured: Load failed**

It could be something to do with CORS or something within my JavaScript. I am new to AWS and JS so I have been asking chatGPT for help along the way.

Below is my javascript:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    const calculateButton = document.getElementById('calculate-button');
    const resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');

    calculateButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Retrieve the values of x and y from the input fields
        const x = parseFloat(document.getElementById('x').value);
        const y = parseFloat(document.getElementById('y').value);

        // Check if x and y are valid numbers
        if (isNaN(x) || isNaN(y)) {
            resultDiv.textContent = 'Please enter valid numbers for x and y.';
            return;
        }

        // Make a GET request to your Lambda function with x and y as query parameters
        fetch(`https://XXXX.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/testing/calculator?x=${x}&y=${y}`)
            .then(response => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                // Handle the response data as needed
                resultDiv.textContent = `Result: ${data.result}`;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                resultDiv.textContent = `An error occurred: ${error.message}`;
                console.error(error);
            });
    });
});
```

Could someone help me out with this issue?

I also am attaching my CORS settings for API gateway
[CORS SETTINGS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8egYX.png)